# Mute all but one app

Tags: volume-control, customization, volume, application-manager, internet-radio

So I have this national radio news app.

Now I should like to use different apps while listening.

This doesn't work.
As soon as I open a different app, the news app gets muted, even when all sounds are turned off in the other app.

How do I change that?

Comment: I don't think it's possible as Android design doesn't permit

Comment: @beeshyams and yet there ARE some apps that overlay their own sound without issues.

Comment: Possibly due to the design of app to overcome this limitation; Android per se doesn't permit it - when an app is minimised it's audio is taken over by foreground app. This is my understanding as a user - I haven't a clue of development